# Connecting to PostGIS using SEXTANTE in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing

I have a localhost PostGIS database that I would like to use with SEXTANTE in QGIS. I can connect to the database just fine using "Add PostGIS layers...", but when I try "PostGIS execute SQL" in SEXTANTE, I´m not sure of what to enter and I can´t find any documentation or examples. All I get is "Wrong database connection name...".

Any suggestions/examples on how to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use the name that you give to one of your defined postgis connections.

Open Add Vector Layer Dialog -> Database -> Check the available connections on the *Connections* combobox and use this exact name as database on the "Postgis execute SQL" option

*Postgis execute SQL" launchs your query to the database. No more, no less. It does not have a rich gui, and it does not produce any output.

Probably if you want to create and launch sql queries within qgis there are two plugins that provides better functionality:

- [RT SQL Layer](http://planet.qgis.org/plugins/rt_sql_layer/)
- [Fast SQL Layer](https://github.com/pablotcarreira/Fast-SQL-Layer) (I think that this is outdated)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Execute SQL" from GDAL geoalgorithms